# How to Setup Stripe && React && Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, react-router, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm really confused and would be hugely grateful to anyone who can help me out here.

I'm building a React web app with a Firebase backend. I need to integrate Stripe into the application so that I can take payments.

I've spent the last few days working through the documentation and tutorials and I must admit, I'm completely stumped.

I've managed to setup stripe so that a new customer is created in Stripe when a new user is created in Firebase, which is definitely a start.

But now I've hit a dead-end. I think the right solution is to create a page where the user can fill out a form with their credit card details. To send those details to Stripe so I'm not storing them and get back a token of some sort. Save that token to firebase and use that a trigger to firebase functions to send that token to Stripe to initiate the payment.

But this is so confusing and there are so many contradictory articles and tutorials that I'm completely lost.

So once again, if anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated. Happy to include my code as needed.

Oh, and I think the fact that I'm using react-router for my navigation is also causing some issues around where to place the  wrapper.

Comment: Could you share what you have so far, maybe share a guide you have been following, as well as the exact errors you have been getting? This will increase the probability of someone finding the solution for you.

Comment: Hi Pessolat, I've created a new question with a lot more detail here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345785/how-to-integrate-stripe-into-a-react-app-with-firebase-hosting-and-firebase-func

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to check out Stripe's [integration builder](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder), which will give you a step by step guide on how to accept payments using React and Node (be sure to select those options at the top).

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately I'm still getting all kinds of errors.